# HTML5 canvas not working on PHP files

Tags: javascript, php, html, canvas

I'm trying to use canvas on a PHP page I created. The same script and code runs on HTML but when I change the extension to PHP and access it on localhost it fails. Here is my HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Canvas</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC">      
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="testcanvas" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="canvas.js"></script>
</body>
```

And my script:

```
'use strict';

$(document).ready(function() {

var cnv = document.getElementById('testcanvas');
var ctx = cnv.getContext('2d');

ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(500,300);
ctx.stroke();

});
```

Is there any reason why this works with HTML and not with PHP?

In case you are wondering what this script should do...

```js
'use strict';

$(document).ready(function() {

  var cnv = document.getElementById('testcanvas');
  var ctx = cnv.getContext('2d');

  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(500, 300);
  ctx.stroke();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="testcanvas" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
```

Comment: Are there any messages on your browser's console? warnings? errors?

Comment: Something says to me that your HTML output from PHP is incorrect.

Comment: Please clarify "fails". And check in the View-source if something is being added or changed in your php code.

Comment: Works fine with .php extension as well here on my UniServerZ. Just tried it. Maybe its a character encoding issue. Try to convert your files to UTF-8 encoding (e.g. with Notepad++). You should also add <!DOCTYPE html> on top of the HTML script. Would be worth a try.

Comment: After testing several Browsers, IE11 seems to have a Problem with that. Maybe that's your issue

Comment: Thank you all for the help. There was really no explanation for this issue. And it turns out it wasn't PHP fault. It was a cache problem. I cleared the cache and the problem is now gone!